# tab bar hide in tab bar based application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Since I start my application with a tab based, now I want to disable entire tab bars,How can I achieve this? Here my code in Appdelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3=[[temptable alloc]initWithNibName:@"temptable" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4=[[about alloc]initWithNibName:@"about" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4, nil]; 
    self.window.rootViewController=[self tabBarController];
    //self.window.rootViewController =viewController2;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I just want to hide the entire tab bars and want to make `viewController2` as main page with navigation controller. Can anyone  help out for this?

Comment: do you want to use your custom tabs or just want to remove tab bar controller ?

Comment: @saadnib i want to remove tab bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this two methods, which I have used to hide & show the tabbar

```m
- (void)hideTabBar {
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    UIView *parent = tabBar.superview; // UILayoutContainerView
    UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0]; // UITransitionView
    UIView *window = parent.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;
                     tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds);
                     tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
                     //content.frame = window.bounds;
                 }];
}

- (void)showTabBar {
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    UIView *parent = tabBar.superview; // UILayoutContainerView
    UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0]; // UITransitionView
    UIView *window = parent.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;
                     tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(tabBar.frame);
                     tabBar.frame = tabFrame;

                     CGRect contentFrame = content.frame;
                     contentFrame.size.height -= tabFrame.size.height;
                 }];
}
```

Comment: instead of hiding how can disable entire tab bar @Shantanu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the UITabBarController instance and just show one of the views you've added to the UITabBarController full screen, what about displaying the view modally over the UITabBarController?

```
UINavigationController navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```